# Excel: Count unique text in column B when column A matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count unique text values in column B when column A matches.

Let's say I have

```
A 1    
A 1    
B 1    
B 2    
C 2    
C 2    
C 2
```

I want it to return

```
A has one unique text in column B    
B has two unique texts in column B    
C has one unique texts in column B
```

Which Excel formula would I use?

Comment: If you truly want the output to be a sentence without giving the A,B,C yourself, you are going to want VBA.  If you want to put A,B,C in a column then have the next column give you the unique numbers then it can be done easily with formula.  But getting the unique Column A is difficult with it in a sentence like that.

Answer (score 2):

With formula you are going to need a couple of helper columns:

In the first we put this array formula in the ***SECOND*** row:

```
=INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))),0))
```

Then in the column next to it this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))=D2,1/COUNTIFS($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),D2,$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))))
```

Both are array formulas. Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then in the third column we can put the text:

```
=D2 & " has " & CHOOSE(E2,"one","two","three") & " unique " & IF(E2>1,"texts","text")& " in column B"
```

If you have greater than three unique you will need to put the text equivalents.

[image]

Comment: OP is away, but I wonder if they could just use numbers instead of "one", "two", "three", as I'm sure it'd help the formula be a little smaller...

Comment: @BruceWayne I was showing how much work would need to go into getting the output exactly like they want.

Answer (score 1):

In cell C1 you can enter the following array formula by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter:

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A7="A",B1:B7),B1:B7)>0))`

Then in Cell D1 enter this normal formula:

`"A has " & C1 & " unique text in column B"`

Repeat in the next three rows down for B and C. If you really want to replace the numeral "1" with the word "one", that will be much harder and I do not recommend it. Also, if you really wanted to get fancy you can modify D1 to use an if statement to check whether or not C1 is more than 1 and if it is add the plural "s" onto the word "text".