# Excel - How to countif within column B excluding duplicate values from column A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

The spreadsheet I am working with houses multiple duplicates for CLIENT_ID and I want to be able to count each CLIENT_ID only once, and then count the amount of a specified value within AGE_CATEGORY.  Basically I want to exclude any duplicates and then countif.

```
| Column A  |   Column B   |
+-----------+--------------+
| CLIENT_ID | AGE_CATEGORY |
| 1514      | 65           |
| 1517      | 65           |
| 1522      | 17           |
| 1519      | 37           |
| 1514      | 65           |
| 1516      | 28           |
| 1503      | 20           |
```

--- I would like for the count for people >=65 to be 2, since client# 1514 appears twice.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please show example data. Post it **as text**, not an image.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)` would return 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is first extract unique values from column A then count those IDs. As per my below screenshot use below formulas <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> formulas.

```
D2 =UNIQUE(A2:A8)
E2 =COUNTIF(A2:A8,D2#)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `UNIQUE()` exists in only the most recent versions of Excel. But, beyond that, I’m not sure this is answering the OP’s question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of unique age (category?) values — say, in Column `D`
— with “Data” → “Sort & Filter” → “Advanced (Filter)”. 
(Sort them if you want.) 
Enter

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$8=D2,A$2:A$8),A$2:A$8)>0))
```

into `E2`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
and copy/drag down. 
This is the result:

```
   |     A     |      B       |      C       |      D       |   E   |
---+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
 1 | CLIENT_ID | AGE_CATEGORY |              | AGE_CATEGORY |       |
 2 |   1514    |          65  |              |          65  |     2 |
 3 |   1517    |          65  |              |          17  |     1 |
 4 |   1522    |          17  |              |          37  |     1 |
 5 |   1519    |          37  |              |          28  |     1 |
 6 |   1514    |          65  |              |          20  |     1 |
 7 |   1516    |          28  |              |              |       |
 8 |   1503    |          20  |              |              |       |
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43265364/1672723#43279314) by SandPiper.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data (to return values) is in `A2:A8` and `criteria` is in `B2:B8` use this **ARRAY** formula to check unique values `>=65`

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$8>=65,MATCH($A$2:$A$8, $A$2:$A$8,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))
```

**Note** for array formula you have to enter this formula with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter` so that `curly braces` appear around the formula automatically.

Needless to say, you can change `>=65` to your criteria accordingly.  sample check see screenshot

[image]